# About the physical definition of the Planck's constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, physical-constants

In Quantum Mechanics (QM), the Planck's constant has the S.I. units of

(energy) x (time). So, how should one interpret that?!

How should I *understand* the physical meaning of the following relations?

$\frac E  \nu = h$

as the  "**energy content**" divided by the "**fastness**'' of oscillation equals h.

or in terms of the de Broglie definition

$ |\vec{p}| \times \lambda= h$

i.e. **particle momentum** times the ``**size**'' of wavelength equals h.

I know that the definitions are linked. However, for the sake of basic understanding, two questions

**a)** Should I understand that the **size** of the wavelength is $\underline{\text{fixed}}$ w.r.t the momentum of the particle and similarly its energy fixes the **fastness** of its oscillations? They are one and the same thing being looked at from different perspective?

**b)** Is there any classical version of a physical constant that has more than one definition like the Planck's constant?

Comment: Your first relation is wrong.  The appropriate equation is $E = h \nu$.

Comment: Ah! thank you. I shall make the typo correction.

Comment: Planck's constant has units of action. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)

Answer (score 2):

There are no two definitions of Planck's constant. In fact, the two relations you gave above are connected. According to Special Relativity, the energy of an object is $$E^2 = (\vec{p} c)^2 + (mc^2)^2$$ But a photon has no mass, so you get $E = \vec{p}c$. And the wavelength of the photon is connected to the frequency ($\nu$). Actually, the wavelength $\lambda$ is equal to ${c}/{\nu}$, where $c$ is the speed of light (and conversely, $\nu = c / \lambda$). So equating, you get: $$h = \frac{E}{\nu} = \frac{\vec{p}c}{c/\lambda} = \vec{p}{\lambda}$$

As for a), actually the relation is $E = h \nu$ and $\lambda = h / {p}$. So the wavelength and momentum are **proportional**, but not fixed w.r.t. each other. In fact the [De-Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave), shows that the wavelength of a particle depends on the momentum. Same for the relation between energy and frequency. The energy of a particular photon is **proportional** to it's frequency, and $h$ is just the proportionality constant between them.

Quick Note:- How the Planck's constant gets the unit $(energy) * (time)$. The unit of the frequency is $1 / T$, where time is the period of the wave measured in seconds. Then you have energy, having SI units Joules. So by $\frac{E}{\nu} = h$, you get $\frac{E}{1 / T} = ET$, hence the units $(energy) * (time)$.

Comment: Wow! yes, this makes so much sense to me now. Using the special relativity here makes it easier to see the connection. What prompted my question was that i wanted to see **energy** x **time** along the lines of how we understand *distance* traveled as **velocity of the particle** x **duration of time**. So, now can we say that the for all the particles **energy** x **time interval** stays constant? or would it be wrong to say that time is **inversely proportional** to energy?  $\Delta E =  \hbar/ \Delta T$.  Then, Planck's constant is just a proportionality constant! isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual. Many quantities have two separate, common expressions in terms of two different sets of other quantities.

For example, the permeability of free space $\mu_0$ has units of $(\text{inductance})/(\text{length})$ and also of $(\text{force})/(\text{current})^2$.

Comment: Yes. But then isn't there the idea of derived units vs basic units or a matter of definition between different unitary systems? The permeability could also be given as  the ratio of **B** to **H** field. However, i wanted to know in **b)** if the two definitions of the Planck's constant arise due to the interlinked physical quantities involved. This is just for a basic conceptual understanding. Thank you for your answer. I think that part **b)** is closed now.

Comment: @Ishika_96_sparkle Neither energy nor momentum are basic units, so there's no difference between the two constants on that front.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I made a mistake in understanding your point.